# Box plot of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
code:

df.boxplot()
```

It returns a plot of all the columns in the dataframe as expected. But it is also returning the text. For example:

```
{'boxes': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x118efc278>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x118f0c668>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x118f20f98>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11d58e908>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11d5a6278>,
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11d5b7ba8>,}
```

Is there a way to remove the text and also any suggestions for  customizing the plot for highlighting the outliers would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: The text is a function response. If you don't like it you can just do `a = df.boxplot()`

Comment: @Greg Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Greg said above, this is a function response.

I'm guessing you are using a Jupyter/IPython notebook to plot inline, so you never have to actually call `plt.show()`.

While you can definitely use `a = df.boxplot()` or even just `df.boxplot();`, I'd recommend you actually make an habit of using `plt.show()`, so that if later on you want to execute your code somewhere else than in an inline jupyter session, you can.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

[...]

In [x]: df.boxplot()
        plt.show()
```